# Not able to get SVG path - Snap.svg

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, snap.svg

In the current init function, I am loading in an SVG using Snap.load and then trying to get that SVG's children 'path' elements; however, the path function is outputting '0' and '0' in the console when running. A timeout function has been set, but that still does not seem to recognize any 'path' elements.

How can I go about getting the SVG 'path' elements to output in the script? Below is an example of the current html and script.

**HTML**

Before the SVG asset has been loaded:

```
<div class="icon-svg-morph" id="icon-svg">
    <svg class="animate-object icon-svg"></svg>
</div>
```

After the SVG asset has been loaded:

```
<div class="icon-svg-morph" id="icon-svg">
    <svg class="animate-object icon-svg" height="150" viewBox="0 0 500 500" width="150">
        <desc>Created with Snap</desc>
        <defs></defs>
        <path
            d="M345,230l-95-95l-95,95l-55,95l150,50l150-50L345,230z M250,334l-54.5-84L141,289
l31-52l78-75l78,75l31,52l-54.5-39L250,334z"
            id="icon-path"
            style="fill: #339ed9;"
        >
    </path>
    </svg>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$.svgElement.prototype = {
    init: function() {
        var s = Snap('.icon-svg');

        Snap.load('asset/img/icon.svg', function (response) {
            var icon = response;
            s.append(icon);
        });

        s.attr({
            height: 150,
            viewBox: 0 + ' ' + 0 + ' ' + 500 + ' ' + 500,
            width: 150
        });

        this.path();
    },

    path: function() {
        var paths = $('.icon-svg').children('path');

        console.log(paths.length);

        if (! paths.length) {
            setTimeout(function(){
                console.log(paths.length);
            }, 100);

            return;
        }
    }
};
```

[Click to view the current example.](http://andrewwierzba.com/development/current/icon-svg.html)

Comment: not sure it will fix it but at least I can tell you that your timeout is useless if you don't update `paths` after the timeout.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the paths, I would just use Snaps selectAll

```
s.selectAll('path') or s.select('path')
```

if you only want one, you may need to make sure s is accessible to the select.